# SQL Query for displaying repeated Date in single row for same user

Tags: sql, pivot, crosstab

Please help me with SQL Query

This is table I have

```
+--------+----------+
|UserID  |Date      |
+--------+----------+
|Sanjay  |29/06/2017|
+--------+----------+
|Sanjay  |30/06/2017|
+--------+----------+
|Sanjay  |26/06/2017|
+--------+----------+
|Vishal  |29/06/2017|
+--------+----------+
|Vishal  |30/06/2017|
+--------+----------+
|Vasanti |29/06/2017|
+--------+----------+
```

Need below desired Output

```
+--------+----------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+--------+
|UserID  |Count     |Date 1      |Date 2      |Date 3     |Date 4     |Date 5  |
+--------+----------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+--------+
|Sanjay  |3         |29/06/2017  |30/06/2017  |26/06/2017 |           |        |
+--------+----------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+--------+
|Vishal  |2         |29/06/2017  |30/06/2017  |           |           |        |
+--------+----------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+--------+
|Vasanti |1         |29/06/2017  |            |           |           |        |
+--------+----------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+--------+
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Tag your question with specific DBMS

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has *PIVOT* operator which could able to do this kind of task

```
with cte as
(
    select *, count(userid) over (partition by userid) Counts,
              concat('Date ', row_number() over (partition by UserID  order by (SELECT 1))) SQ
    from table
)

select * from 
(
    select * from cte
)a 
PIVOT (
    MAX(Dates) for SQ IN ([Date 1], [Date 2], [Date 3])
)P
order by 2 desc
```

Full Dynamic pivot way

```
declare @cols varchar(200), @query varchar(2000)

SET @cols = STUFF(
                  (select DISTINCT  ','+QUOTENAME(concat('Date ', row_number() over (partition by UserID  order by (SELECT 1))))
                   from table for xml path('')),1,1, '')

set @query  = 'select * from 
               (
                  select *, 
                         count(userid) over (partition by userid) Counts,
                         concat(''Date '', row_number() over (partition by UserID  order by (SELECT 1))) SQ
                  from table
               )a PIVOT (
                    MAX(Dates) for SQ IN ('+@cols+'))P
               order by 2 desc'

exec (@query)
```

**Result :**

```
UserID  Counts  Date 1      Date 2      Date 3
Sanjay  3       29/06/2017  30/06/2017  26/06/2017
Vishal  2       29/06/2017  30/06/2017  NULL
Vasant  1       29/06/2017  NULL        NULL
```

Comment: It is fixed for 3 dates, what if he got more records like he mentioned in question Date 4 and Date 5?

Comment: @AamirNakhwa... This just kind of idea BTW... dynamic pivot way would help as i mentioned.